# Page Break in jsPDF when converting HTML to PDF using jsPDF

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf

I was trying to convert a HTML template in angular to pdf using jsPDF.

To be more precise I was having a very large html content with custom styles in ngFor Loop. The issue was I don't know when & how to make page break correctly.

Consider I'm having a Form content followed by a table in my HTML template.
What happens in the above scenario is, the Form content taking 75% of the PDF page and because of this my table header still remains in the same PDF page and the table body goes to next PDF page.

I want to properly do a page break in between  dynamically. I don't want add 
 tags & making the content to move to next page.

How can I solve this ?

Quick Sample in StackBlitz.
[`StackBlitz Sample Code Here`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-k2yhsv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Please generate the PDF and check, to understand the issue more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

To properly handle page breaks when converting an Angular HTML template to a PDF using jsPDF, you can follow these steps:

Define a CSS class called "page-break" with the property page-break-inside: avoid;. Apply this class to the container element of your form content.

Use JavaScript to calculate the height of the content and determine when a page break is needed. If a page break is required, call addPage() to start a new page in jsPDF.

Iterate through the pages and render the content using fromHTML().

By using the "page-break" class and the JavaScript logic described, you can dynamically insert page breaks in your PDF, ensuring that your table header stays together with the table body on the same page.

CSS

```
.page-break {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

html

```
<div class="page-break">
  <!-- Your form content here -->
</div>
```

Javascript

```
// Calculate the height of the content
const contentHeight = document.querySelector('.page-break').offsetHeight;

// Set the maximum height of each page (adjust as needed)
const maxHeightPerPage = 800; // For example, assuming each page can hold up to 800px of content

// Calculate the number of pages needed
const totalPages = Math.ceil(contentHeight / maxHeightPerPage);

// Generate the PDF
const pdf = new jsPDF();

// Loop through the pages
for (let i = 0; i < totalPages; i++) {
  if (i > 0) {
    pdf.addPage(); // Add a new page for subsequent pages
  }

  // Render the content of the current page
  pdf.fromHTML(document.body, 15, 15, { pagesplit: true });
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Are you sure this works inlatest version of jsPDF ?